# Laravel model and forms

Tags: php, forms, laravel

Data does not enter database from form input.

this is part of the code in my controller. Database table name is projects and as per the following to the input names.

```
$project = new Project;
        $project -> projectName = $request -> ProjectName;
        $project -> dateline = $request -> dateline;
        $project -> startDate = $request -> startDate;
        $project -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
        return redirect('/projects');
```

Comment: What do you mean by database name is project ?? Project should be table name right ?/

Comment: sorry my bad. edited it

Comment: where is your `save` method.Try `$project->save()` before `redirect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You miss the `save()` method.

```
$project = new Project;
$project->projectName = $request->ProjectName;
$project->dateline = $request->dateline;
$project->startDate = $request->startDate;
$project->users_id = Auth::user()->id;
$project->save();
return redirect('/projects');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do like this.
First make your own request for this controller. 
For example `ProjectRequest`.Then in the controller write

> **Note** Yout input field should be `project_name`, `start_date` .

```
 public function store(ProjectRequest $request)
     {
         $input = $request->only([
             'project_name',
             'dateline',
             'start_date'
         ]);

         $project = new Project();
         $project-> projectName = $input['project_name'];
         $project-> dateline = $input['dateline']; 
         $project-> startDate = $input['start_date']; 
         $project -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
         $project->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to `save()` data in the table. Check with the below code .

```
 $project = new Project;
            $project -> projectName = $request -> ProjectName;
            $project -> dateline = $request -> dateline;
            $project -> startDate = $request -> startDate;
            $project -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $project->save();
            return redirect('/projects');
```

For more information see [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent)